# Putting Objects in the JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, object, jdbc

I am wondering how will I implement this classes I made in the JDBC, you see,I created a class like User,Employee, FinanceMember , SystemAdmin, and all of them have references to classes like PersonalInformation,ContactInformation, when I code all I can think of is they are going to be objects, but How will I enter their date in the JDBC? Will I pass these objects to any mysql Api? or there's something specific I should do??

Comment: Consider using a Object Relation Mapping system like Hibernate

Comment: I have no idea how mapping system works, or how will I implement them, is there any guide?? to that?

Comment: Have a look at the Java EE 6 tutorial: http://www.amazon.com/Java-Persistence-Hibernate-Christian-Bauer/dp/1932394885/ref=pd_sim_b_4

I also can recommend the book "Java Persistence with Hibernate": http://www.amazon.com/Java-Persistence-Hibernate-Christian-Bauer/dp/1932394885/ref=pd_sim_b_4

Comment: I need to finish this project within 3 weeks, and btw I am not making it for java EE it's a standlone project, not java EE

Comment: JPA can be used in standalone projects as well. Use transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" and manage the transactions manually.

Comment: How would I set the transaction type?

Answer (score 1):

Have look at a JPA implementation (e.g. EclipseLink or Hibernate), which is a O/R-mapping framework.

JPA is based on JDBC.

Edit:

> I need to finish this project within 3 weeks,

If you don't have time to learn JPA (though I recommend to learn it), but are familiar with JDBC, have a look at JdbcTemplate from the Spring framework. You can use it even if you don't use Spring. 
It helps with managing resources and mapping to objects.

Comment: I really want to learn JPA trust me, but time won't allow me, after this project I'll revised my code with JPA, but right now I need to get this going, btw, where can I see Jdbc template??? and yeah this is a stand alone, not java ee

Comment: Search for "JdbcTemplate" and "Spring" and make sure you get the latest version.